# Visual Studio Code переход к концу строки

Tags: visual-studio-code, hotkeys

подскажите пожалуйста существует ли такое сочетание клавиш из коробки, если существует то какое, ну или как его сделать самому. В результатах поисковой выдачи ответа не нашёл. Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто нажимаете на клавишу **End** на клавиатуре.

Answer (score 1):

`End` - windows, `Command + стрелка в нужную сторону` - MacOS 
Это в принципе работает для всего, не только VSCode.